# Display dialog - IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I want to display an AlertDialog, when the dialog should be appear I get the next message:

> IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or
>   descendant) with this activity.

This is the code i'm using to display the dialog:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext())
                .setTitle("Not set yet :(")
                .setMessage("You haven't set the directories to search in... Do you want to set it now?")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                })
                .show();
```

This is the MainActivity headline:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

This is my styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

I've tried to looking for answers over the internet and couldn't find an answer,
how do I fix this problem?
I need an ActionBar, do I need to change the inheritance? Or should I change something in the AndroidManifest.xml or in styles.xml?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your **style.xml**

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

And use this for show Dialog (exit dialog example) in your **MainActivity.java**:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourMainActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title));
builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.exit_dialog));
builder.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok_dialog), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                         YourMainActivity.this.finish();
                                }
                            });
builder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.cancel_dialog), null);
builder.show();
```

Than in **string.xml**:

```
<string name="cancel_dialog">CANCEL</string>
<string name="ok_dialog">OK</string>
<string name="exit_dialog">Are you sure you want to quit?</string>
<string name="title">Your App Title</string>
```

In **colors.xml** (optional):

```
<item name="colorAccent" type="color">#FFFF8800</item>
<item name="colorPrimary" type="color">#FFCC0000</item>
```

Comment: Great solution, worked for me, but why did it not work originally? We were both clearly using AppCompat themes....